# Scipy odeint with banded Jacobian matrix

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm integrating a system of stiff ODE's using SciPy's integrate.odeint function. As the integration is non-trivial and time consuming I'm also using the corresponding jacobian. By rearranging the equations I can define the jacobian to be a banded matrix. Following the [API documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) I would like to define the shape with the *mu* and *ml* params. Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit ambiguous so that I was not able to figure out how to implement my jacobian function.

In order to verify how *odeint* has to be called, I've been using the following (somewhat silly) code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
lmax = 5

def f1(y, t):
    ydot = np.zeros(lmax)
    for i in range(lmax):
        ydot[i] = y[i]**2-y[i]**3
    return ydot

def fulljac(y, t,):
    J = np.zeros((lmax, lmax))
    J[0,0]=-3*y[0]**2 + 2*y[0]
    J[1,1]=-3*y[1]**2 + 2*y[1]
    J[2,2]=-3*y[2]**2 + 2*y[2]
    J[3,3]=-3*y[3]**2 + 2*y[3]
    J[4,4]=-3*y[4]**2 + 2*y[4]
    return J

## initial conditions and output times
delta = 0.0001;
yini  = np.array([delta]*lmax)
times = np.linspace(0, 2/delta, 100)

y, infodict = odeint(f1, yini, times, Dfun=fulljac, full_output=1)
print("f1: nst: {0}, nfe: {1}, nje: {2}".format(infodict["nst"][-1],
                                                infodict["nfe"][-1],
                                                infodict["nje"][-1]))
```

Using the full NxN jacobian matrix the integration is successfull. Using only the diagonal and *mu=0* and *ml=0* the integration succeeds as well.

To test the banded matrix use case I'm creating an artificial 3xN banded jacobian using *mu=1* and *ml=1*, where all the derivatives off the diagonal are zero. This causes a weird behavior of the solver (similar to what I see in my original problem where the off-diagonals are non zero).

```
def bandjac(y, t):
    J = np.zeros((lmax, 3))
    J[0,1]=-3*y[0]**2 + 2*y[0]
    J[1,1]=-3*y[1]**2 + 2*y[1]
    J[2,1]=-3*y[2]**2 + 2*y[2]
    J[3,1]=-3*y[3]**2 + 2*y[3]
    J[4,1]=-3*y[4]**2 + 2*y[4]
    return J

y, infodict = odeint(f1, yini, times, Dfun=bandjac, full_output=1, mu=1, ml=1)
print("f1: nst: {0}, nfe: {1}, nje: {2}".format(infodict["nst"][-1],
                                                infodict["nfe"][-1],
                                                infodict["nje"][-1]))
```

What is the proper way to use the banded jacobian option with SciPy's integrate.odeint?

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  There was a bug in how `odeint` handled banded Jacobians that was fixed in scipy 0.14.0 (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3145).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this. I was using SciPy 0.13.x.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I’m replying to my own question.

As pointed out by Warren Weckesser there is a [bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3145) in Scipy <0.14.0 on how odeint handles banded jacobians.

The current documentation of odeint states:

> Dfun should return a matrix whose rows contain the non-zero bands (starting with the lowest diagonal).

Which I believe is incorrect. Instead it should start with the **highest** diagonal.

The following code snippet shows how *Dfun* should return the jacobian (derived from the [*test_integrate.py* unit test](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/tests/test_integrate.py)):

```
def func(y, t, c):
    return c.dot(y)

def jac(y, t, c):
    return c

def bjac_rows(y, t, c):
    return np.array([[   0,    75,       1,  0.2], # mu - upper 
                     [ -50,  -0.1,  -1e-04,  -40], # diagonal
                     [ 0.2,   0.1,    -0.2,   0]]) # lower - ml

c = array([[-50,    75,     0,   0],
            [0.2, -0.1,     1,   0],
            [0,    0.1, -1e-4,   0.2],
            [0,      0,   -0.2, -40]])

y0 = arange(4)

t = np.linspace(0, 50, 6)

# using the full jacobian
sol0, info0 = odeint(func, y0, t, args=(c,), full_output=True,Dfun=jac)
print("f1: nst: {0}, nfe: {1}, nje: {2}".format(info0["nst"][-1],
                                                info0["nfe"][-1],
                                                info0["nje"][-1]))

# using the row based banded jacobian
sol2, info2 = odeint(func, y0, t, args=(c,), full_output=True,Dfun=bjac_rows, ml=1, mu=1)
print("f1: nst: {0}, nfe: {1}, nje: {2}".format(info2["nst"][-1],
                                                info2["nfe"][-1],
                                                info2["nje"][-1]))
```

**Note**: the transposed banded matrix does not seem to work with *col_deriv=True*

Comment: Don't get too excited about upgrading to 0.14.0. While experimenting with your code, I discovered that there is still a bug in the handling of a banded Jacobian by `odeint`.  It is probably the cause of the problem you see when using `col_deriv=True`.  In general, the bug could potentially cause a problem when `col_deriv=False`, but in your example, it worked OK.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: My initial question was on how to properly implement the banded jacobian as the online documentation isn’t clear about this, hence my reply. Regardless of that, I also think that there is a bug in SciPy with `col_deriv=True`.

Comment: transposed banded matrix seems to work for me now in scipy 0.18.0... and it's faster

Answer (score 0):

I made a function to convert a jacobian matrix to banded form as expected by `odeint`, as well as the `mu` and `ml` parameters. The input is expected to be an `np.array`. For best performance, you probably want to turn the result matrix into an `np.array`, and then have the jacobian function return its transpose, and use `col_der=True`. I think BrainGrylls is correct that you should start with the highest diagonal first, contrary to the current API documentation.

```
def make_banded_jacobian(matrix):
    '''returns a banded jacobian list (in odeint's format), along with mu and ml parameters'''

    # first find the values of mu and ml
    dims = matrix.shape[0]
    assert dims == matrix.shape[1]
    mu = 0
    ml = 0

    for row in xrange(dims):
        for col in xrange(dims):
            if matrix[row][col] != 0:
                if col > row:
                    dif = col - row
                    mu = max(mu, dif)
                else:
                    dif = row - col
                    ml = max(ml, dif)

    banded = []

    for yoffset in xrange(-mu, ml+1):
        row = []

        for diag in xrange(dims):
            x_index = diag
            y_index = diag + yoffset

            if y_index < 0 or y_index >= dims:
                row.append(0.0)
            else:
                row.append(matrix[y_index][x_index])

        banded.append(row)

    return (banded, mu, ml)
```